# Codeigniter 404 not found on ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I have an application with Codeigniter, but when I run it using Xampp on Ubuntu I get a 404 error.

The htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule> 

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

If I create a new codeigniter project, it works. The problem happens with a project that was created on Windows and I want to test it on Ubuntu.

I'm running on local, and the directory is: opt/lampp/htdocs/Alcaldia

Comment: have you check your apache config file?

Comment: I downloaded an empty codeigniter project and it worked. The one I am trying to open was used on Windows before

Comment: what is your url means folder structure?

Comment: I'm testing in localhost, it should work with localhost/Alcaldia

Comment: As you said you are using ubuntu, there is an apache config file which must be allowOverride to true to navigate to other page from home page. So please confirm once "AllowOverride is All" or not...

Comment: Ensure that your .htaccess file is enabled by setting AllowOverride to All.

Comment: @PHPGeek I can confirm that AllowOverride is All. My folder structure is /opt/lampp/htdocs/Alcaldia. I tried with another project in codeigniter, but a new one and it worked

Comment: put RewriteBase /Alcaldia/ after RewriteEngine on in .htaccess file

Comment: @GufranHasan I just did it and it didn't work

Comment: see this https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/codeigniter-3-and-cgi-fastcgi-solved/223069

Answer (score 0):

try this in your htaccess file.

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```